# Reading books can cultivate our mental development

Tags: meaning

> Reading books can cultivate our mental development.

Is this sentence correct? Should both *cultivate* and *development* be used together here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, [cultivate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cultivate) means to:

> 2
>   a : to foster the growth of

which, in concert with *development* would compose a redundancy.

You may however *cultivate mental toughness*, or *promote mental development* if that's what you meant.

Comment: You could argue however that *mental development* itself is a process, and to cultivate it would be to increase its pace.

Comment: the former is indeed a process, though, cultivate doesn't mean accelerate.